# Copy a user selected row to the next blank row on a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 2 worksheets.  sheet 1 is open and sheet 2 is closed cases

i am trying to copy the values from a user selected row and paste these into the next blank row on the closed sheet.

I have a VBA which does this but I think it can be reduced, but dont know how to do it.

My current code is as follows.  DRow is a calculated calue and works fine, Irow is gotten from a message box and again works fine

```
    Worksheets("Closed").Cells(DRow, 2).Value = Worksheets("Open").Cells(iRow, 2).Value
    Worksheets("Closed").Cells(DRow, 3).Value = Worksheets("Open").Cells(iRow, 3).Value
    Worksheets("Closed").Cells(DRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("Open").Cells(iRow, 4).Value
    Worksheets("Closed").Cells(DRow, 5).Value = Worksheets("Open").Cells(iRow, 5).Value
    Worksheets("Closed").Cells(DRow, 6).Value = Worksheets("Open").Cells(iRow, 6).Value
    Worksheets("Closed").Cells(DRow, 7).Value = Worksheets("Open").Cells(iRow, 7).Value
    Worksheets("Closed").Cells(DRow, 8).Value = Worksheets("Open").Cells(iRow, 8).Value
    Worksheets("Closed").Cells(DRow, 9).Value = Worksheets("Open").Cells(iRow, 9).Value
```

Is there a way to condense this into one or two lines

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `.Resize` :

```
Worksheets("Closed").Cells(DRow, 2).Resize(1,7).Value = _
    Worksheets("Open").Cells(iRow, 2).Resize(1,7).Value
```

Comment: thank you very much.  really helped.  what does resize do?

Comment: @NeilCapper - see [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: @Jeeped : Thx for the link, I didn't take time to add it. @ NeilCapper : It'll litteraly resize the range that you are working with, see the link for more details! ;)

Comment: @NeilCapper : As you don't have accepted the answer, I guess that you haven't take the Tour, please take a minute to read it : http://stackoverflow.com/tour